# SQL not returning the proper values

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are:

```
Equipment table 
EquipmentID (pk) 
Type 
Make 
Model 
Damaged
Description

EquipmentLoan table 
EmployeeID
EquipmentID (fk Equipment.EquipmentID) 
Start 
End 
Current
```

I am trying to return the equipment ID, make, model and description of equipment that

- Is not marked as damaged
- Not currently on loan
- Have the word 'video' in its type or description

However, the code I currently have:

```
SELECT Equipment.EquipmentID,Equipment.Make,Equipment.Model,Equipment.Description 
FROM Equipment 
INNER JOIN EquipmentLoan ON Equipment.EquipmentID=EquipmentLoan.EquipmentID 
WHERE Equipment.Damaged = 0 
AND EquipmentLoan.Current = 0 
AND (Equipment.Type LIKE "%video%" OR Equipment.Description LIKE "%video%")
```

This currently returns no results, when there should be two results returned.

However when I use the query:

```
SELECT e.EquipmentID, e.Make, e.Model, e.Description 
FROM Equipment e, EquipmentLoan l 
WHERE e.Damaged = 0 
AND l.Current = 0 
AND (e.Type LIKE "%video%" or e.Description LIKE "%video%")
```

The correct results are returned, along with an extra result that doesn't match the conditions. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Please post a sample of your inputs, as well as current and desired output.

Comment: Your last query has no joining condition between the tables, so you get a full cross product of all the matching rows.

Comment: @Barmar, and one of the reasons implicit joins are ill-advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query only returns equipment that has a matching row in `EquipmentLoan` and that row has `Current = 0`. If you also want equipment that has no matching row at all, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN`. Then you check if this returns `NULL` for the lack of a match.

```
SELECT e.EquipmentID,e.Make,e.Model,e.Description 
FROM Equipment AS e
LEFT JOIN EquipmentLoan AS l ON e.EquipmentID=l.EquipmentID AND l.Current = 1
WHERE e.Damaged = 0 
AND (e.Type LIKE "%video%" OR e.Description LIKE "%video%")
AND l.EquipmentID IS NULL
```